# Persistent bar at the bottom above BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, footer

Is it possible to have a persistent Container (or any widget for that matter), that sits above the bottom navigation bar and is persistent across various pages? Everything else, the top appBar and the bottom navigation bar should change per page as usual.

I searched quite a bit, and there are a few ways I can make the navigation bar itself persistent (eg. [Persistent widget at the bottom of every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912708/persistent-widget-at-the-bottom-of-every-page)), but unable to find anything, or think of anything.

One option is to add a blank container to each screen, and add an overlay maybe? But wondering if there is a better way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate widget ScreenWrapper. You can give any name. Add child Widget parameter in that. Use Column in that widget. First child of column will be

Expanded(child: child),

Note: Here, child is any screen of your app that you will pass in this widget.

Second widget will be your persistent container.

Wrap your all screens with ScreenWrapper.

ScreenWrapper(child: AnyScreen())

Comment: I need the bottom-navbar to change per page i.e. the bottom navbar will a part of the `child`. So if I just make the second row in the column persistent, I still need a third row which needs to specific to the page.

Comment: If each page has specific and separate nav bar. Then, why don't you create separate widget for persistent container. And, call that widget in each screen.

Comment: Nope, I want different navbar per page, but the same persistent bar across all pages. If it was different persistent bar, then the solution is simple :). Anyways, I was able to get it to work via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675525/how-to-keep-a-custom-widget-common-across-more-than-one-screen-in-flutter. Thanks for trying to help :)